# Was Vs Were in the sentence?

Tags: verbs

> The office with all its modern furniture and equipments **were/was** sold for
>   a meagre amount.

As per my understanding it should be **were** because we're connecting the two entity with **and** but my friend told me that when we use **with**, **along** the verb is decided by the first subject. Hence, **was** is apt here. This led me to a trouble. Please clear my doubt.

Comment: Preposition ‘with’ doesn’t really make your singular subject ‘office’ into plural. ‘With’ doesn’t work like conjunction ‘and’. See, this example of plural subjects using plural verb: The office and the company car were sold at a profit.

Answer (score 8):

Here you need to be clear what the subject of the sentence is, i.e., what is *being sold*. The subject is "office" and it *includes* furniture and equipment. Hence, the correct verb would be *was* which is the appropriate one for "office". The equipment and furniture are not subjects here.

Comment: +1. I agree. As with Sudhir's example in a similar question, the structure can be made clearer by placing _with all its modern furniture and equipments_ between commas.

Comment: +1 The "giveaway" is that the phrase *with all its modern furniture and equipments* can be moved without changing the meaning of the sentence: *The office was sold for a meagre amount, with all its modern furniture and equipments.*